# Out-File does not produce the same data as export-csv

Tags: excel, powershell, printing

Evening,

I'm trying to get a list of all users that have permissions on 3000+ printers at a site, I've been trying to separate the SID's that are outputted into their own separate columns which I haven't been able to do. I'm trying to get Export-CSV to show the same data as Out-File because I'm sure I can do this with Export-CSV. Here is what I have.

```
$printers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\FinalPrinters3020.txt 
(Get-Printer $printers -Full).PermissionSDDL | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation 
-Path \\FileServer\Printerlist\Printers30202.csv
```

When I do this I get this:
[image: Wrong data]

When I use Out-File:

```
$printers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\FinalPrinters3020.txt 
(Get-Printer $printers -Full).PermissionSDDL | Out-File 
'\\FileServer\Printerlist\Printers30202.csv'
```

And I get how the data should look:
[image: Correct]

Answer (score 2):

`Export-Csv` will only export the properties an object contains.

Use `Get-Printer $printers -Full | Select-Object PermissionSDDL | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation`

In your example you are sending string objects and `Export-Csv` will use the length property as that is the only property strings contain. Verify this with `(Get-Printer -Full).PermissionSDDL | gm -MemberType Properties`

With the `Select-Object` cmdlet a custom object is returned that contains the properties you want and `Export-Csv` will output the result you want. Contrast the first example with `Get-Printer -Full | select PermissionSDDL | gm -MemberType Properties`

Comment: That got the export-csv to work correctly thank you, now any idea on how I can insert a comma between SIDs or at least get each SID to its own cell?Here is how it comes across now:  G:SYD:(A;;LCSWSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-3923692831-1208425469-611280938-4391465)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-3923692831-1208425469-611280938-4391465)(A;CI;SWRC;;;WD)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;AC)